# Disable autocomplete in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: autocomplete, libreoffice-calc

Autocomplete can be nice, but for me it's usually *not* what I want in LibreOffice Calc. Is there a way to disable it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Is there a way to disable autocomplete?

Go to menu "Tools" > "Cell Contents" > Uncheck "AutoInput"

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

In LibreOffice Calc 5+ that menu item has been moved.

Go to menu "Tools" > Uncheck "AutoInput"

[image]

Comment: I have no AutoInput in that menu. LibreOffice Calc 5.1

Comment: @Alexey It's been moved. See updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

Uncheck "AutoInput" in the "Tools" menu:

[image: Calc AutoInput]

with the new LibreOffice 5.